# NativeScript 2.0 [1.7.1] build is failing at 'processF0DebugResources' when gulp related dependencies are added to 'devDependencies' section

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp, nativescript, gulp-typescript

NativeScript 2.0 (I'm using NativeScript-Angular) build is [tns build android] failing at 'processF0DebugResources' when gulp related dependencies are added to 'devDependencies' section.

This is happening since 1.7.1 too, but, I was of the impression that it would be fixed in 2.0 release. It looks like the devDependencies are getting built too.

I also tried `gradlew -debug` which showed no errors and there is no .apk file generated too when this error occurs.

**Here is the exception:**

```
:processF0DebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processF0DebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process ' command 'C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**Here is my package.json:**

```
    "dependencies": {
    "tns-core-modules": "2.0.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "0.0.46",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.16",
    "nativescript-intl": "0.0.2",
    "parse5": "1.4.2",
    "punycode": "1.3.2",
    "querystring": "0.2.0",
    "url": "0.10.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.8.0",
    "babel-types": "6.8.1",
    "babylon": "6.8.0",
    "filewalker": "0.1.2",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-connect": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.1",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resolved!!

Instead of using `npm install`, I used `tns install`, which built all the devDependencies correctly and I was able to deploy my app successfully.

Thanks to Hristo Deshev for helping me out on this.

Comment: I had to delete the "node_modules" and "platforms" folders before running tns install as I had already run npm install. But this solved the issue for me as well - Thanks!

Comment: Also remove "hooks" folder as you can bump into the following error after this one `Cannot find module 'nativescript-unit-test-runner/lib/after-prepare'`

Comment: gets me everytime :/